# ffmpegで動画を分割。

Tags: ffmpeg, 動画

ffmpegで動画を分割する場合、指定秒数を指定回数のみ分割ってできますか？
例えば30分のTS動画があるとします。
動画の最初から1分間ずつ5回の分割を行うことを指定できますか？

Answer (score 1):

環境が不明ですので例示はしませんが、時間指定オプションを動的に生成するスクリプトをつくればそういった複雑な処理も可能です。

ここではffmpegだけでできる方法を述べます。時間指定`-ss/-t`で動画全体の範囲を制約して、`segment`フォーマットで分割処理をすることで、回数指定に近いことができるとおもいます。具体的には

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 0 -t 300 -f segment -segment_time 60 output_%02d.ts
```

のように指定します。この場合、input.tsの時間にかかわらず、冒頭5分間を1分ごとに、すなわち5回分割します。残りの部分は

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 300 output_remain.ts
```

で取得できます。

ただし、エンコードなしでの分割は動画コーデックの制約から正確には分割されないことが多いです。きっちり1分に収める必要性がある場合は、動画の再エンコードを指定するオプションを指定してください。

各オプション、フォーマットについて詳細は[ドキュメント](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)をご確認ください。以上、参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、範囲指定とは思いつきませんでした。